# How do I increase width size for Editable Bootstrap TextBox?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

This is my code:

JS:

```
$('.edit').editable();
```

HTML:

```
<li class='edit' style='cursor=hand'>I want to edit this</li>
```

If someone clicks on this `<li>` menu then Bootstrap editable box appears but its too small. How do I increase its size? I checked Google but could not find the right answer.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a code simple ?

Comment: li class='edit' style='cursor:hand' > This is a my code </li>

Comment: are you using this plugin with BS3 ? http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

Comment: I'm just using Bootstrap class named 'editable' and its working... i just want to increase the width size

Comment: can you provide us a jsfiddle

Comment: THanks its fixed. I used  $('.edit').editable({type:  'textarea'})

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.edit {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 14px; }
```

You can re-work those properties depending on the desired look.

Comment: It doesnt work . I want to increase the size of the editable box not my li .

Comment: I assumed that the li with a class of .edit became a textarea or input with the same class. Inspect the editable box and see what the class/id is and just use that for the CSS.

Comment: it works this way but working bootstrap css it not recommended i guess. i used this code and worked.         $('.edit').editable({type:  'textarea'})